# Mocking a Class used within a Context Manager

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a module method that uses a context manager with a Class that offers iteration:

```
import module

def ReadLog(log_file):
  with module.LogReader(log_file) as reader:
    combined_list = []
    for record in reader:
      combined_list.append(record)
    return combined_list
```

In my unittest, I'm trying to mock module.LogReader such that it produces records defined by myself.  This is where I'm at so far:

```
import mock
import my_mod

@mock.patch.object(my_mod.module, 'LogReader')
def testReadLog(self, mock_logreader):
  filename = '/fake/file/name.log'
  my_mod.ReadLog(filename)

  # Verify that module.LogReader was called
  mock_logreader.assert_called_once_with(filename)
```

But I haven't been able to make the iteration produce records so far.  The LogReader class has `__enter__, __exit__, __iter__, next` methods, and I've tried doing `mock_logreader.return_value = '123'` for example but this results in the error message `AttributeError: __exit__`.

What sauce am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `return_value` on the functions you want to mock, before you call the function you're testing. Note that on anything where you haven't set this, it'll return a new `MagicMock`. You can intercept this by setting a `return_value` on this new `MagicMock`.

So for example:

```
file = 'foo' 
mock = MagicMock()  # could be gotten through patch
mock(file).__enter__().__iter__.return_value = [1,2,3,4,5]

with mock(file) as reader:
    for x in reader:
        print(x)
```

See the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html) for how the magic functions work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I had to slightly modify -- in my case I needed something like `mock(filename).__enter__().__iter__.return_value = [1,2,3,4,5]` -- could you update your answer to reflect that?

Comment: right, that's what you get for editing from your phone before you had breakfast.